# Importing JAR file package name

Tags: java, import, jar

I'm pretty new to java and with some googling I haven't found an answer. I have a JAR file that is correctly added to my classpath. How am I supposed to know what the package name for the jar file is if it is never given to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jar is a normal zip file. open this file and look at the directory structure.

/org/apache/xyz/MyClass.class

will be

import org.apache.xyz.MyClass;

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse, when you type some class/interface that your class didn't import yet, eclipse will do the red highlight. You just need to hit ctrl+1 over it, a list will show up with some options like

> Import '**class you are trying to use**' (**full package path to class**)

Or you could refer to that jar documentation on which package to import. Bottomline is that typing by hand is not very productive, ctrl+1 and ctrl+shift+o are your friends(if you are using Eclipse).

Comment: For a shorter shortcut try Ctrl+Shift+O = "Organize imports." This will add any missing imports (as long as they are available, of course) and organize the imports into a logical order.

Comment: @dj18 Thanks for the tip. So used to just hit on keyboard that didn't remember well the full shortcut.